# Java FileWriter help

Tags: java, filewriter

Okay... so I have a fairly interesting error... I declare a FileWriter called file, and I have it go through the following for loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.radtot; i++) {
    file.write("" + i * a.rstep);

    for (int n = 0; n < a.timetot; n++) {
        file.write("\t " + T[n][i]);
        System.out.println(T[n][i] + " " + n + " " + i);
    }

    file.write("\n");
}
```

At the end of it, the System.out.println command prints what I expect it to, but the file cuts off midway... As in, instead of printing out everything System.out does... it stops in the middle. Does anyone happen to know why it would do that? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call [`close()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#close()) on the `FileWriter` when you're done with it. This forces all output to be actually written to disk (it could be left in a buffer otherwise).

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.radtot; i++) {
    file.write("" + i * a.rstep);

    for (int n = 0; n < a.timetot; n++) {
        file.write("\t " + T[n][i]);
        System.out.println(T[n][i] + " " + n + " " + i);
    }

    file.write("\n");
}
file.close(); // <-- Add this
```

(I'm assuming you've omitted exception handling for brevity, so I have done the same. The `close()` would ordinarily be in a `finally` block to ensure that it will always run.)

Comment: Technically speaking flush() was what was missing, but close() is a good idea in any case.

Comment: Yes, I think the Javadocs make that clear (and I didn't want to clutter the answer up).

Answer (score 3):

Try adding:

```
file.close();
```

The [`close()`](http://file:///Users/jared/Documents/Specifications/jdk-6u10-docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#close()) method description says:

> Closes the stream, flushing it first.